# how can an Activity get interface calls from its adapter

Tags: android, interface, adapter, dataflow

I have an activity ,which has a **listview** and an **adapter**. From the adapter I am calling a **Dialog fragment** and the dialogue fragment does some events and an interface is written to get the   results to the adapter, now I need to do some UI changes from activity according to the result, how can I pass the result to the activity ..

**activity--->adapter--->fragment-->interface**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by interface . follow below 4 steps

1 create one interface

```
  interface abc(){
   void callDialogFragment()
}
```

2. intialise that interface object in adapter constructor

   abc mLisetner;

   mLisetner=(abc)mContext;
       // call the method in specific listner

   mLisetner.callDialogFragment()
3. Implement the interface on activity
4. define the overide method on actvity and call dialogFragment

   @override
     public callDialogFragment(){

   // call your dialog here 
   }

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution:

The `fragment` would **must** have `activity`'s reference. So inside the `DialogFragment` you can call:

```
((YourActivityName)getActivity()).anyPublicMethodOfActivity(someData);
```

If you put some code, I can tell you how the `fragment` has got `activity`'s reference.

Answer (score 0):

This does look really coupled design. 
I would like to see some code to understand what exactly you have done. 
I guess you have passed the activity reference to the adapter with which you display a fragment.

Technically, your activity can implement your interface and the fragment could use the activity's reference to call interface's method, but it looks a really bad design.

Check https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus but even this, DO NOT overuse.